# replace ubuntu with windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I am running Ubuntu 13.04 right now and i would like to go back to windows.  I have a windows 7 iso and tried booting it from the usb but it brought up a command screen and i had no idea what to do there. What I am trying to do is basically uninstall Ubuntu and install windows back on my laptop

Comment: This is really an Ubuntu forum, but if you make sure that your USB drive appears above the drive which is host to your Ubuntu installation, in the BIOS of your computer, You should, if the iso is correctly formatted, bring up your Windows installation screen.

Comment: Use [UUI(Universal USB Installer)](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to make a USB bootable.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a bootable win usb? (See more info on this [here](http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/).)

Also, make sure your bios is set to boot from your usb drive first.

You'll have to format your partition (sda) to ntfs using GParted from the linux live cd/usb

Comment: I did not make it bootable, I  just put it on the USB. terrible mistake

Comment: What software can I use to make a bootable USB?